# iframe inside contentplaceholder in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm using masterpage. I have a page and I need a frame with 2 columns. In the left side I have links like <kbd>show cities</kbd> and <kbd>show details</kbd>.

If i click <kbd>show cities</kbd> it should display citypage.aspx in the right side. Similarly for another link.

My iframe code is

```
<frameset rows="100%" frameborder="0" border="0">
<!--<frame src="../Forms/header2HisIssue.aspx" scrolling="no" noresize="0">-->
<frameset cols="35%,65%" frameborder="2px" border="2px" bordercolor="red">
<frame src="Addition.aspx" name="workarea1" scrolling="no" noresize="0">
<frame src="AddPage.aspx" name="workarea"  noresize="0">
</frameset>
```

But my page is showing seperately. Why?

Answer (score 0):

What's the meaning of showing separately?
If you using a link on left to open a page on right. You have to use the name of right iframe as the target of the link.